# How to pass an argument with quotes and spaces to Process.StartInfo

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run the equivalent command below using c# and Process.StartInfo and read the result into a string.

```
>wget2.exe ME.GR2 -match ":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:"
```

The difficulty is finding the correct syntax for the second argument **-match ":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:"** for it to be correctly understood by  Process.StartInfo.Argument.

For throuble shooting various cases were tested using ArgsEcho.exe based [these examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netstandard-2.1#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-arguments).

The required output from ArgsEcho.exe is below. The quotes as well as spaces after **-match** and before **mb** are needed:

```
[0] = ME.GR2
[1] = -match ":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:"
```

Below is a small sample of some of the test results using the value in the command variable and the code at at the end - all unsuccessful. Similar results were seen using ArgumentList.

```
command = "ME.GR2 -match \":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:\""

[0] = ME.GR2
[1] = -match
[2] = :(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:

command = "ME.GR2 -match \"\"\":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:\"\"\""

[0] = ME.GR2
[1] = -match
[2] = ":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:"
```

Any guidance on how to correctly format the Argument value to achieve the required result would be appreciated.

Test code:

```
public string ProcessCmd(string command)
{
    string output = "";
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"ArgsEcho.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;

        //process.StartInfo.FileName = @"wget2.exe";
        //foreach (string str in args)
        //{
        //     process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add(str);
        //}
        //process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.Start();
    
        // Synchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
        //StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
        //output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    
        //process.WaitForExit();
    }
    
    return output;  //empty for tests
}
```

Comment: `@"ME.GR2 ""-match """":(UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(200|500) mb:"""""""` maybe?